# for loop not working correctly with debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, for-loop

I have to copy one array to another. Both of them are in int* form. I have to copy it till the index reads -1, but it keeps on copying. I tried using the debugger. After reaching -1 it carries on copying data in the rest of the vertices.

```
void copy(int *a, int *b)
{
    int i=0;

    while(a[i]!=-1)
    {
        if(a[i]==-1)
            break;
        //for( i=0; a[i]!=-1; i++)
            a[i]=b[i];
        i++;
    }

    a[i]=b[i];
}


copy(temp->patharray,num);
```

patharray and num are both int*

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question without showing your arrays.

Comment: isn't that `if` redundant?

Comment: num contain 1 2 3 4 -1 I want it to be copied till -1

Comment: And yes it is. I was trying different ways to get it to stop at -1 but it just wouldn't!

Comment: Do you mind 1) fix your indentation 2) fix your title so that it looks less like "your program fails only when running as a debuggee"

Comment: Solving my problem right now is more important, isn't it? I have to submit it tomorrow night!

Comment: TOM. I LOVE YOU. I have been working all night on this. So worked up. I can't believe I made this mistake. Thankyou. I LOVE YOU OKAY!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume the size of array b is equal to array a,

```
void copy(int *a, int *b)
{
    int i=0;

    while(b[i]!=-1)  
    {
        a[i]=b[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to copy till you have `-1` in source array, but all your checks are against previous value in destination array

```
while(b[i]!=-1)
{ 
   a[i] = b[i];
   i++;
}
```

Side note: having good variable names makes code easier to read and understand - try

```
void copy(int *destination, int *source, int maxLength) 
{
  int currentIndex = 0;

  while(currentIndex < maxLength && source[currentIndex] != -1)
  {
     destination[currentIndex] = source[currentIndex];
     currentIndex++;
  }
}
```

Comment: THANKYOU. I was so worked up. Been working all night! LOVE YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You are testing `a[i]` *after* you have incremented `i`.  This means that you have not yet assigned `a[i]`.  May be you should be checking for `b[i] != -1`.